# Auto-layout: UILabel inside UIView with padding

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I'm trying to get to grips with auto layout, but am struggling to see how to achieve something which used to be straightforward. I have a `UILabel *label` with intrinsic size, that I want to place inside a `UIView *container`. The label should have 20 points padding so it is centered vertically and horizontally inside the container.

Several similar questions have pointed to overriding the `intrinsicContentSize` method, but this will not work for labels with multiple lines of text, and requires that I subclass the label.

I have tried the following:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[label]-20-|"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[label]-20-|"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
```

which does give the container the correct size, but throws warnings with the label still situated in the top-left corner.

Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong? I'm sure I'm just not *getting* it yet, but auto-layout seems rather complex for such a simple task.

**UPDATE**: here's 1 of 2 errors I'm getting (second is same but for the vertical contraint).

```
2015-10-08 13:36:58.869 Thinger[17498:8116452] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7c23c480 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7c140b80'Hello world'.midX == + 38.5>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7c2bb500 h=--& v=--& H:[UILabel:0x7c140b80'Hello world'(77)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c144b10 H:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x7c140b80'Hello world']   (Names: '|':BigButtonView:0x7c142460 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c144b10 H:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x7c140b80'Hello world']   (Names: '|':BigButtonView:0x7c142460 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: share the warning message with us

Comment: Can you please let us know what is the warning you're getting.

Comment: @baydi -  I just set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` on the label which seems to have worked. Is this the correct way to do it? Thanks for responding.

Comment: you should not give leading and trailing constraints to make it center. Try giving centreX and centr Y constraints.